# How to send email with table via Outlook through Delphi 7

Tags: html, email, delphi, outlook

I would like my Delphi program to send email message via Outlook which will contain table (like the ones in Excel). I know how to send emails using Outlook through Delphi, but do not know how to include tables in it. I guess this should be something related to html code inside email body, but do not know exactly. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Outlook email object has a property htmlbody. You can set the value of this property to the html code of the message. To create the correct html code, have a look at www.w3schools.com. They have a lot of information about creating tables in html.